# Programar Resta-Um utilizando Método de Monte Carlo

Tags: java, algoritmo

Tenho pouca experiencia em Java e estou a tentar aplicar o Metodo de Monte Carlo em Teoria Combinatorial de Jogos. Estou a tentar demonstrar o Metodo no Jogo Resta-Um onde tera de ser resolvido utilizando passos aleatorios. Para o metodo ser efetivo cerca de 10 000 simulacoes terao de ser feitas, as vitorias e os passos mais efectivos tem de ser registados. 
O metodo de Monte Carlo ja foram aplicados em outros jogos como por exemplo Go Computer. 
Os problemas que tenho tido e na estrura do projeto, se e melhor ter tudo separado por classes, como registar as os resultados, e como organizar o programa de modo a jogar aleatoriamente.

ate agora tenho a estrura basica do jogo, e a logica por detras dos passos permitidos.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2637/132

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Defina uma estrutura de dados

Em alto nível, basicamente você precisa definir uma estrutura de dados adequada para representar o tabuleiro para o Jogo.

No caso de Java, pode ser um array bidimensional com a largura e altura do tabuleiro. Por exemplo:

```
int[][] tabuleiro;
```

## Defina como as informações serão representadas

Como este array não pode ser deformado para se adequar ao tabuleiro, sugiro iniciar ele com os valores:

- `-1` (um negativo) onde for proibido colocar peças
- `0` (zero) para ausência de peças
- `1` (um) onde houver uma peça

## Inicialize com o estado inicial

Crie um método que preencha os valores em todo o vetor, seguindo as regras mencionadas acima, conforme o tabuleiro inicial do jogo.

## Implemente as regras do Jogo

Implemente um método para movimentar as peças:

```
mover(origemX, origemY, destinoX, destinoY)
```

O método deve verificar se o movimento é permitido ou não. Por exemplo;

1. A posição de origem deve ter uma peça, isto é, o valor do array na posição `(origemX, origemY)` deve ser igual a `1`.
2. A posição de destino não deve conter uma peça e deve ser uma posição válida, isto é, o valor do array na posição `(destinoX, destinoY)` deve ser igual a `0`.
3. A diferença de posições entre origem e destino deve ser de duas casas na vertical ou na horizontal.
4. Deve haver uma peça entre a origem e o destino.

E assim por diante. Os tópicos acima são apenas um resumo simples para fazer o movimento.

Depois de verificar se o movimento é possível, o método deve então aplicar as alterações no vetor para realizar o movimento:

1. A posição de origem do array recebe `0`.
2. A posição de destino do array recebe `1`.
3. A peça que foi "pulada" do array recebe `0`.

## Implemente o algoritmo de solução

Agora que você já tem o tabuleiro e a ação implementada, terá que implementar também a solução.

Infelizmente, não sei como solucionar este tabuleiro usando o método de Monte Carlo, então não tenho como dar uma direção inicial nesse ponto.

Entretanto, antes de implementar qualquer coisa, você deve resolver o problema primeiro. Isso significa que você deve ter em algum lugar uma especificação do algoritmo que resolve.

Depois que tiver esse algoritmo, isto é, uma sequência de passos que resolve o problema após uma quantidade limitada de iterações, então ficará bem mais fácil pensar numa solução juntando tudo o que você tem.

## Registro das operações

Registrar os passos realizados pelo algoritmo de solução é algo até bem simples.

Em cada passo do algoritmo, imprime no console ou em um arquivo texto as "decisões" tomadas.

Além disso, no método `mover()` mencionado acima, imprima também o movimento que está sendo realizado. Por exemplo:

> Movendo peça de (origemX, origemY) para (destinoX, destinoY)

Ou no caso de ser um movimento inválido:

> Tentativa de movimento inválida de (origemX, origemY) para (destinoX, destinoY)

Somente com esse rastreio você poderá reconstruir o jogo passo a passo em um tabuleiro real.

Comment: Sobre o tal método, http://home.comcast.net/~gibell/pegsolitaire/EnglishResults.html